# nesting an svg inside a div

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a filled svg triangle which will be placed at *some* place on the page.

To accomplish this I wrap the svg in a div and place the div appropriately. However, the svg is always rendered outside of the div. How do I get the svg element rendered inside the div?

I can't use the `<object>` or the `<embed>` tag due to scripting and templating constraints

Sample HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner_container">
        <svg height="6" width="6">
            <path d="M 0 6 L 3 0 L 6 6 L 0 6"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#container {width:100px; height:25px; border:1px solid green;}
#container #inner_container {width:6px; height:6px; border:1px solid red;}
#inner_container  svg path {fill:black;}
```

The filled triangle should be inside the red rectangle but is rendered outside

See it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/648hF/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the css selector, write only `svg{...}` and add `float:left`

Here path is just a drawing not an element.

```
svg {fill:black; float:left}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/648hF/1/)**

Comment: Yep floating "Svg" does the trick. But "fill" is an attribute of "path" so I guess I will leave it in the path selector

Comment: Can anybody explain *why* the original breaks?  I notice the problem disappears if I change 6 to 60 throughout, so this seems to only be an issue for small divs/svgs - very inconsistent behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#container { float: left; width: 100px; height: 25px; border: 1px solid green; }
#container #inner_container { float: left; width: 6px; height: 6px; border: 1px solid red; }
#inner_container svg { display: block; float: left; }
```

I add some floats in there so that they 'contain' the elements. There are better and more elegant ways to do this, but it should work.

Hope this helps.
Mikey.

Comment: Just being curious, could you elucidate on "more elegant ways"? I have had a lot of trouble in trying to fit my svg inside the divs lately

Comment: Well, floating every single element isn't the best way to do something like this, because it isn't always necessary to do so, but in situations like this where I don't know the full extent of what's going on, it's usually a good quick fix to float elements which usually stops them collapsing in on themselves. Hope that makes sense? Also, depending on your structure, floating everything could cause layout issues.

Comment: Yep, floating everything would be a disaster

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you didn't specify namespace for `svg` element. This is how it works:

```
<div id="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 0 6 L 3 0 L 6 6 L 0 6"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I experienced the same issue as described in the question. I have tested out your solution and it didn't solve the issue. The solution provided by Sowmya